# mongodb - query for array of objects containing two values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a chat app, and when a user starts a new conversation, I want to check if a conversation between those two users already exists.

My Conversation modal looks something like:

```
  {
    members: {
      type: [
        {
          username: String,
          email: String,
          id: String,
          avatar: String,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

And to find all conversations where one of the members contains a user's ID, I use

```
db.collection.find({
      members: { $elemMatch: { id: userID } },
})
```

Which works perfectly.

But I can't figure out how to find Conversations where the `members` include user1ID and user2ID

Comment: do you want all conversations where members have both id1 and id12

Comment: correct, both id1 and id2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator too check if the conversation members have all the specified user ids

```js
db.collection.find({
  "members.id": {
    "$all": [
      user1ID,
      user2ID
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qsxo-gxCi5i)

Answer (score 1):

using `$and` operator you can also do this way

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "members": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "id": userId1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "members": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "id": userId2
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Both answers seem to work, which is better though?

Comment: both are doing the same thing and both perform equally, use what you like.